# Get list of docker ip containers

Tags: networking

Let's say I have docker, which is running x amount of containers. Is it possible to somehow get a list of all the containers ip addresses?

I wish to bake this into a script somehow.

`docker ps -a`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
614497a23ca7        mongo               "/entrypoint.sh mongo"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes             27017/tcp           some-mongo
```

I've looked at the docker api and it doesn't really seem to have what I'm looking for. I'd like it to return for example:

```
172.17.0.2
... other ips addresses
```

I know `docker inspect` exists and I could pipe the data and extract the `IPAddress` field, but that is for a single container. I'd like all of the containers ip addresses. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to try and find a Docker container by its IP address you can list out the container ids and their IP addresses like so:

```
for container in `docker ps -q`; do ips=`docker inspect $container | grep -i ipaddress | grep -v null | grep -v \"\" | cut -d ':' -f 2`; echo $container$ips; done
```

You can also do something like this (which prints out container names instead of container ids):

```
docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect --format "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{print .IPAddress}} {{end}}{{.Name}}"
```

Comment: This appears to be very similar to [13dimitar’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1167922/150988#1167938).  How is it different?  Is it better? Why? … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

How about the below?

```
for i in `docker ps -q`; do echo $i; echo " : "; docker inspect $i | grep -i ipaddress | grep -v null | cut -d ':' -f 2; done
```